# Unable to filter search with "user:me"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Filtering search results using [`user:me`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me) no longer works; it shows no results (and the search options say `user:`, with nothing after it). Searching by ID (e.g. [`user:309308`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:309308)) still works

Comment: +1 - Somehow, I had just searched on this couple of days back and it was working. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bonehead regex placement by me to cleanup some edge cases, it's fixed in the next build...long term we're looking at refactoring search quite a bit more maintainable - it's a *little* complicated behind the scenes at the moment.