# Search for question in questions list that I've answered

Tags: discussion, questions, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to filter search with “user:me”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78751/unable-to-filter-search-with-userme)

Sometimes i show question that have been asked previously means exactly duplicate. Now I've answered the previously asked question. so now if i have to search for question in my home page i have to go through all questions until i get the right one so i can give duplicate question url.

> **Is there functionality available to search for a specific question in question list that I've
>   answered on SO?**

---

### Edit:-

As [Sachin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150894/sachin-shanbhag) said in his answer we can search by `user:me <text>` but its not working currently.

> So is there any other option for this?
>
> When will `user:me` starts working?

Comment: @Nick: that question is not my duplicate. I'm asking about searching technique in SO not that `user:me` is not proper.  My edit asks that question but my main question is techniques for searching a question in SO.

Comment: True it's not an *exact* duplicate (though it is a duplicate of many *other* questions), I pointed it there because people finding this having issues need to see it's fixed :)

Comment: @Nick: can i have other duplicate questions for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such functionality in the SO. you need to type "`user:me <search keywords>`" in the search textbox on SO. You can also use "`user:<yourid> <search keywords>`". This will search for keywords in all your questions and answers.

Unfortunately, this feature is not working currently - [Unable to filter search with "user:me"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78751/unable-to-filter-search-with-userme)

Comment: will you please provide an example?

Comment: @Harry - Unfortunately, this feature is currently not working in SO as given in my link. Once this bug is fixed, it will start working. :(

Comment: see the edit.